# Setting up a HTTP Receiver in Tibco Businessworks for an existing Web Service

Tags: web-services, tibco, businessworks

So currently I managed to reach an existant Web Service and use one of it's functions to alter a database.
However, the Web Service does not respond with a Soap Response, but with just the HTTP Respond Code 200, which I want to use to create a "Success!"-like notification.

Using BusinessWorks I was able to to connect the process with a HTTP Receiver in the Modeler-View, but it doesn't work and gives me the error message
"Process configuration error. The activity [HTTPReceiver] in the process [webservices.module.IWSContract] cannot have an input transition."

My goal is to catch the HTTP Response Code 200 from the Web Service, and optionally display it to the user.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention you use TIBCO BW 6. this should be the "Invoke" activity instead of SOAPRequestreply (Basic Palette -> Invoke)
[image]

Comment: Should I use Invoke to invoke a HTTP Receiver, or how does Invoke work for me?

Comment: As far as i understand you try to invoke a Web Service with BW acting as a client(send HTTP Requests). The HTTP Receiver is the opposite and acts as a server(in both BW 5.x and BW 6.x) made to receive HTTP Requests.

Comment: Maybe I phrased it wrong. I already invoked the Web Service, and am able to communicate with it. Now, after the task is done, the Web Service sends a "response", the HTTP Success Code 200, which I want to catch and optionally display a "Successfully completed" note to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a **SOAP Request-Reply** activity to invoke the web service. Technically, the "HTTP 200" response won't be visible but you will get an empty output in case of a success:

[image]

You can then choose to return whatever success message to the user.

Comment: So I just tried it, but my Businessworks is version 6.x. I cannot find any SOAP-palettes to use, so I tried using a lone HTTP Receiver and configure i to lisen to a specific port. However, I cannot manage that, either.